# Best way to authenticate from C# WPF on PHP website

Tags: c#, php, wpf, authentication

I am writing a WPF application that I need to authenticate with our current PHP based online website. I have full control other both, so any recommendation is possible.

I do not know whether it would be best to use:

1. Pass the username and password via post/get to an API and see if the user is "valid"
2. Connect to the database directly (probably not a good idea)
3. JSON or XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. For security and communication between client and server use the WebClient Object, Or, if you wanna go pro, search a web service generator for php and work with web service standards.
2. only the server should be able to communicate with db, security, abstraction and orthogonality are good reasons for that.
3. Json makes the data thinner, so it's recommended, but if you don't care about data size, xml can be directly bounded to wpf controls, maybe it can help you.